# How do I access a boolean from a different class?

Tags: java, android, class, variables

I'm working on a project where if you press on Break In on the main activity (MainActivityWithButtons) it opens to a page for you to enter your address and from there when you push a button it sends an SMS with a specific message. I need to choose that message using booleans. If you tap break in, it sets a boolean called breakIn to true. I now need to access the breakIn boolean and the value(either true or false, in this case true) in order to use if else statements to choose the message. My problem is that even when my booleans are set to true and I press the button to send the SMS, my app crashes! Please help me, here's the code snippet(s):

MainActivityWithButtons:

```
package com.apps.testp;

import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivityWithButtons extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static boolean breakin;
    public static boolean storeRobbery;
    public static boolean carTheft;
    public static boolean assault;
    public static boolean fighting;
    public static boolean shotsFired;
    public static boolean changeAddress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_with_buttons);

    Button breakIn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.houseBreakIn);
    Button robbery=(Button)findViewById(R.id.storeRobbery);
    Button car=(Button)findViewById(R.id.carTheft);
    Button assaulting=(Button)findViewById(R.id.assault);
    Button shots=(Button)findViewById(R.id.shotsFired);
    Button fight=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fighting);
    Button address=(Button)findViewById(R.id.setOrChangeAddress);



    address.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
            changeAddress=true;
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });



    breakIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
            breakin=true;
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });



    robbery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
                storeRobbery=true;
                startActivity(i);

                }
            });



    car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
            carTheft=true;
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    assaulting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
            assault=true;
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    shots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
            shotsFired=true;
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


    fight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
            fighting=true;
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });



    //Next Listener Goes Here
}




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_with_buttons, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

LocationSelectFromAlertButtons:

```
package com.apps.testp;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class LocationSelectFromAlertButtons extends MainActivityWithButtons{
DBAdapter myDB;
String addressInTV;
Button save;
TextView currentAddress;
EditText addressNew;
Button cancel;
MainActivityWithButtons mainAct;

String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_select_from_alert_buttons);
    setTitle("Please Select Which Address to Use");
    mainAct = new MainActivityWithButtons();
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    currentAddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CurrAddress);
    addressNew=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tbNewAddress);
    cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelBtn);

    final boolean breakIn=MainActivityWithButtons.breakin;
    final boolean storeRobbery=MainActivityWithButtons.storeRobbery;
    final boolean carTheft=MainActivityWithButtons.carTheft;
    final boolean assault=MainActivityWithButtons.assault;
    final boolean shotsFired=MainActivityWithButtons.shotsFired;
    final boolean fighting=MainActivityWithButtons.fighting;
    final boolean address=MainActivityWithButtons.changeAddress;



    openDB();

    Cursor cursor=myDB.getAllRows();
    displayAddress(cursor);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addressInTV = LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this.addressNew.getText().toString();
            myDB.deleteAll();
            long newId = myDB.insertRow(addressInTV);
            Intent i = new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    currentAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(breakIn){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Break In!'/n'"+message , null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(storeRobbery){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Store Robbery!'/n'"+message, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(carTheft){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Car Theft!'/n'"+message, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(assault){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Assault!'/n'"+message, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(fighting){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Fighting!'/n'"+message, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(shotsFired){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Shots Fired!'/n'"+message, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(breakIn){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Break In!'/n'"+addressInTV , null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(storeRobbery){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Store Robbery!'/n'"+addressInTV, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(carTheft){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Car Theft!'/n'"+addressInTV, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(assault){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Assault!'/n'"+addressInTV, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(fighting){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Fighting!'/n'"+addressInTV, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(shotsFired==true){
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage("+27719276502", null, "Shots Fired!'/n'"+addressInTV, null, null);
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if(address){
                Intent intent=new Intent(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.this, MainActivityWithButtons.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        }

        });


}

private void displayAddress(Cursor cursor) {
    String message="No Currently Set Addresses";
    //reset cursor to start
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        //process data
        int id=cursor.getInt(0);
        String address=cursor.getString(1);

        message= address;



    }
    currentAddress.setText(message);
    cursor.close();
}

private void openDB() {
    myDB = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDB.open();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void closeDB() {

    myDB.close();
}









@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location_select_from_alert_buttons,
            menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**EDIT**
Log:

```
  07-20 16:22:30.791  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
07-20 16:22:30.791  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/SELinux﹕ SELinux: VERIFYSIG  File Open Unsuccessful:
07-20 16:22:30.791  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig or checkHash fails. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9500_4.4.2_0024
07-20 16:22:30.791  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts
07-20 16:22:30.796  30308-30308/com.apps.testp E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
07-20 16:22:30.796  30308-30308/com.apps.testp E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.apps.testp [ userId:0 | appId:10127 ]
07-20 16:22:30.796  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-20 16:22:30.906  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
07-20 16:22:30.906  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
07-20 16:22:30.966  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
07-20 16:22:30.971  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 411: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
07-20 16:22:30.971  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-20 16:22:30.971  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
07-20 16:22:30.971  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 433: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
07-20 16:22:30.971  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-20 16:22:31.151  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-20 16:24:27.716  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
07-20 16:24:27.716  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
07-20 16:24:27.781  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
07-20 16:24:27.781  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 374: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-20 16:24:27.781  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-20 16:24:27.781  30308-30308/com.apps.testp I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
07-20 16:24:27.781  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 376: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-20 16:24:27.781  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
07-20 16:24:33.081  30308-30308/com.apps.testp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-20 16:24:33.081  30308-30308/com.apps.testp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420a4c08)
07-20 16:24:33.086  30308-30308/com.apps.testp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.apps.testp, PID: 30308
    java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10127 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
            at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:934)
            at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:137)
            at com.apps.testp.LocationSelectFromAlertButtons$3.onClick(LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.java:77)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT**

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.apps.testp">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.apps.testp.MainActivityWithButtons"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.apps.testp.LocationSelectFromAlertButtons"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_location_select_from_alert_buttons"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
</application>
```

If you need any more info, PLEASE feel free to comment and ask me for it :)
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: What exception does the log show when your app crashes? Can you post that also?

Comment: Sorry, yes, sure, give me a sec

Comment: @KyleBrooks Have you added SMS permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have, I'll post my Manifest file

Comment: Thanks everyone, but now that it's sending my messages (my permission was in the wrong place) I need it to not send a message when they click to change their address, but it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send them through your intent.

In MainActivityWithButtons:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivityWithButtons.this, LocationSelectFromAlertButtons.class);
i.putExtra("some_unique_string1", your_boolean_variable)
startActivity(i);
```

In LocationSelectFromAlertButtons, onCreate():

```
boolean your_boolean_variable = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("some_unique_string1", false);
```

Comment: And then how do I use the intent extra? To send the specific message do I use your_boolean_variable as the variable for the message?

Comment: Is boolean variable true and false or breakIn?

Answer (score 0):

Save your boolean as part of `SharedPreferences`. Then you can access it from anywhere in your application.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putBoolean(BOOLEAN_NAME, boolean).apply();
```

Comment: Thanks, I just don't understand one thing, what does MODE_PRIVATE mean?

Comment: File creation mode: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID). - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE